# Standard deviation using CUDA

Tags: cuda, standard-deviation

I am writing a code to find the mean and standard deviation of 6 vectors with 8000 elements each. I was wondering if I could do it using CUDA and speed up the operation. I could think of how to find the mean using CUDA but I am unable to understand how to calculate standard deviation using CUDA. Can anyone help me here please?

Comment: A few floating point operations on 48000 numbers is at least a hundred times too few to get enough speed up to make using CUDA worthwhile. GPUs like lots of data, you simply have too little. The latency in moving the data to the GPU and initialising the calculation will be larger than the time it would take to perform the calculation in a *spreadsheet* on any host CPU built in the last decade. At that problem size, you can't win.

Comment: this is just a small subset... I actually have 20 million X 6 elements to process

Comment: Why didn't you say that in the question then?

Comment: Sorry... should have mentioned that...

Comment: To add to the options of useful library calls, ArrayFire (which I work on) supports standard deviation and other statistics functions, http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/python/group__stat.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem in CUDA for data mining. I havent used any libraries. But, it gave me good results. The problem is to find the standard deviation and mean of 128*1 million samples. This is what i did.

1. My device has the shared memory of 16KB. And, i am using floats. So, the shared memory can accommodate 4,000 elements. The max thread per block for my device is 512. So, i can have 8 blocks. If i divide 16KB into 8 blocks, i'll get 2,000KB (i.e., 1 float for 1 thread). Generally, this wont match. If you have a better device you need to do this math again.
2. To find the standard deviation, each block has 512 elements. You can find the square(element-mean) using a single thread.
3. The next challenge is adding this and finding the sum of these elements. Try the same method you employed for finding the mean. For 512 elements. Copy the result to global memory.
4. Iterate. Find the square root of the result.

PS: Plan accordingly so that the global memory calls are minimum. Mean and Standard deviation calls the data frequently from the memory.

Answer (score 6):

[Here is a Thrust example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/summary_statistics.cu) that calculates a number of summary statistics in a single pass, including mean and std. deviation.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

// This example computes several statistical properties of a data
// series in a single reduction.  The algorithm is described in detail here:
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Parallel_algorithm
//
// Thanks to Joseph Rhoads for contributing this example


// structure used to accumulate the moments and other 
// statistical properties encountered so far.
template <typename T>
struct summary_stats_data
{
    T n;
    T min;
    T max;
    T mean;
    T M2;
    T M3;
    T M4;

    // initialize to the identity element
    void initialize()
    {
      n = mean = M2 = M3 = M4 = 0;
      min = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
      max = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    }

    T variance()   { return M2 / (n - 1); }
    T variance_n() { return M2 / n; }
    T skewness()   { return std::sqrt(n) * M3 / std::pow(M2, (T) 1.5); }
    T kurtosis()   { return n * M4 / (M2 * M2); }
};

// stats_unary_op is a functor that takes in a value x and
// returns a variace_data whose mean value is initialized to x.
template <typename T>
struct summary_stats_unary_op
{
    __host__ __device__
    summary_stats_data<T> operator()(const T& x) const
    {
         summary_stats_data<T> result;
         result.n    = 1;
         result.min  = x;
         result.max  = x;
         result.mean = x;
         result.M2   = 0;
         result.M3   = 0;
         result.M4   = 0;

         return result;
    }
};

// summary_stats_binary_op is a functor that accepts two summary_stats_data 
// structs and returns a new summary_stats_data which are an
// approximation to the summary_stats for 
// all values that have been agregated so far
template <typename T>
struct summary_stats_binary_op 
    : public thrust::binary_function<const summary_stats_data<T>&, 
                                     const summary_stats_data<T>&,
                                           summary_stats_data<T> >
{
    __host__ __device__
    summary_stats_data<T> operator()(const summary_stats_data<T>& x, const summary_stats_data <T>& y) const
    {
        summary_stats_data<T> result;

        // precompute some common subexpressions
        T n  = x.n + y.n;
        T n2 = n  * n;
        T n3 = n2 * n;

        T delta  = y.mean - x.mean;
        T delta2 = delta  * delta;
        T delta3 = delta2 * delta;
        T delta4 = delta3 * delta;

        //Basic number of samples (n), min, and max
        result.n   = n;
        result.min = thrust::min(x.min, y.min);
        result.max = thrust::max(x.max, y.max);

        result.mean = x.mean + delta * y.n / n;

        result.M2  = x.M2 + y.M2;
        result.M2 += delta2 * x.n * y.n / n;

        result.M3  = x.M3 + y.M3;
        result.M3 += delta3 * x.n * y.n * (x.n - y.n) / n2; 
        result.M3 += (T) 3.0 * delta * (x.n * y.M2 - y.n * x.M2) / n;

        result.M4  = x.M4 + y.M4;
        result.M4 += delta4 * x.n * y.n * (x.n * x.n - x.n * y.n + y.n * y.n) / n3;
        result.M4 += (T) 6.0 * delta2 * (x.n * x.n * y.M2 + y.n * y.n * x.M2) / n2;
        result.M4 += (T) 4.0 * delta * (x.n * y.M3 - y.n * x.M3) / n;

        return result;
    }
};

template <typename Iterator>
void print_range(const std::string& name, Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type T;

    std::cout << name << ": ";
    thrust::copy(first, last, std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, " "));  
    std::cout << "\n";
}


int main(void)
{
    typedef float T;

    // initialize host array
    T h_x[] = {4, 7, 13, 16};

    // transfer to device
    thrust::device_vector<T> d_x(h_x, h_x + sizeof(h_x) / sizeof(T));

    // setup arguments
    summary_stats_unary_op<T>  unary_op;
    summary_stats_binary_op<T> binary_op;
    summary_stats_data<T>      init;

    init.initialize();

    // compute summary statistics
    summary_stats_data<T> result = thrust::transform_reduce(d_x.begin(), d_x.end(), unary_op, init, binary_op);

    std::cout <<"******Summary Statistics Example*****"<<std::endl;
    print_range("The data", d_x.begin(), d_x.end());

    std::cout <<"Count              : "<< result.n << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Minimum            : "<< result.min <<std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Maximum            : "<< result.max <<std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Mean               : "<< result.mean << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Variance           : "<< result.variance() << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Standard Deviation : "<< std::sqrt(result.variance_n()) << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Skewness           : "<< result.skewness() << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Kurtosis           : "<< result.kurtosis() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is outside my area of expertise, but there are single-pass iterative algorithms for computing standard deviation which may be convertible into a reduction. In particular, I am thinking of Welford's Algorithm, as described in Knuth, TAOCP, vol. 2. One drawback is that it requires a division at every step, but this will likely balance well with necessary memory accesses. A useable online reference for the algorithm appears to be:

http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but I have solved this problem using [`thrust::transform_reduce`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformed__reductions.html#ga0d4232a9685675f488c3cc847111e48d) in my code (tested with 100k floats on a GTX 1070):

```
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

#include <functional>
#include <cmath>

/*
 * @struct varianceshifteop
 * @brief a unary function that shifts input data
 * by their mean and computes the squares of them
 */
struct varianceshifteop
    : std::unary_function<float, float>
{
    varianceshifteop(float m)
        : mean(m)
    { /* no-op */ }

    const float mean;

    __device__ float operator()(float data) const
    {
        return ::pow(data - mean, 2.0f);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    thrust::device_vector<float> data{ ... };

    // sum elements and divide by the number of elements
    float mean = thrust::reduce(
        data.cbegin(),
        data.cend(),
        0.0f,
        thrust::plus<float>()) / data.size();

    // shift elements by mean, square, and add them
    float variance = thrust::transform_reduce(
            data.cbegin(),
            data.cend(),
            varianceshifteop(mean),
            0.0f,
            thrust::plus<float>()) / (data.size() - 1);

    // standard dev is just a sqrt away
    float stdv = std::sqrtf(variance);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to finding the mean and variance of a vector using [Thrust](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html):

```cpp
template <typename T> struct square {
    __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T& x) const {
        return x * x;
    }
};

template <typename T> void mean_and_var(T a, int n, double* p_mean, double* p_var) {
    double sum = thrust::reduce(a, &a[n], 0.0, thrust::plus<double>());
    double sum_square = thrust::transform_reduce(
        a,
        &a[n],
        square<double>(),
        0.0,
        thrust::plus<double>()
    );
    double mean = sum / n;
    *p_mean = mean;
    *p_var = (sum_square / n) - mean*mean;
}
```

Here is that solution in a self-contained source file along with some profiling information, comparing CPU to GPU (NB to answer the question exactly as asked, it would be necessary to call the `mean_and_var` 6 times on the 6 different vectors of length 8000, but this should give you the gist):

```cpp
#include "stdio.h"
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

#define PROFILING_INIT                                              \
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;                                        \
    float elapsedTime;

#define PROFILING_START                                             \
    cudaEventCreate(&start);                                        \
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);                                         \
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

#define PROFILING_STOP                                              \
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);                                       \
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);                                     \
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start, stop);                \
    printf("Time elapsed:  %.3g ms\n", elapsedTime);

#define N (6*8000)
// #define N (6*8000*10)
// #define N (6*8000*100)
double a[N];

template <typename T> struct square {
    __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T& x) const {
        return x * x;
    }
};

void mean_and_var_cpu(double* a, int n, double* p_mean, double* p_var) {
    double sum = 0, sum_square = 0, mean;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += a[i];
        sum_square += (a[i] * a[i]);
    }
    mean = sum / n;
    *p_mean = mean;
    *p_var = (sum_square / n) - mean*mean;
}

template <typename T> void mean_and_var(T a, int n, double* p_mean, double* p_var) {
    double sum = thrust::reduce(a, &a[n], 0.0, thrust::plus<double>());
    double sum_square = thrust::transform_reduce(a, &a[n], square<double>(), 0.0, thrust::plus<double>());
    double mean = sum / n;
    *p_mean = mean;
    *p_var = (sum_square / n) - mean*mean;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }

    double mean, var;

    PROFILING_INIT;

    printf("With thrust:\n");
    PROFILING_START;
    mean_and_var<double*>(a, N, &mean, &var);
    PROFILING_STOP;
    printf("Mean = %f, var = %f\n", mean, var);

    printf("With thrust, using device memory:\n");
    thrust::device_vector<double> a_dev(N);
    thrust::copy(a, &a[N], a_dev.begin());
    PROFILING_START;
    mean_and_var<thrust::device_ptr<double>>(&a_dev[0], N, &mean, &var);
    PROFILING_STOP;
    printf("Mean = %f, var = %f\n", mean, var);

    printf("On CPU:\n");
    PROFILING_START;
    mean_and_var_cpu(a, N, &mean, &var);
    PROFILING_STOP;
    printf("Mean = %f, var = %f\n", mean, var);

}
```

Apologies for code quality (I'm predominantly a C programmer trying to adjust to C++ for the purposes of Thrust) and the lack of comments.

In all cases, the answers agree with the mean and population variance calculated using the Python `statistics` module:

```py
import statistics
x = 8000*6
print(statistics.mean(list(range(x))))
# print(statistics.variance(list(range(x))))
print(statistics.pvariance(list(range(x))))
```

Here is some profiling information, all of which was performed on a Jetson Nano development board:

| N | Time taken for Thrust (ms) | Time taken for Thrust using device memory (ms) | Time taken for naive CPU implementation (ms) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6*8000 | 11.2 | 2.38 | 1.11 |
| 6*8000*10 | 108 | 7.62 | 11.7 |
| 6*8000*100 | 1.12e+03 | 41.7 | 109 |

Conclusions from profiling:

- If you're going to use Thrust, make sure you use device memory!
- For a large enough input size, the GPU is faster than the CPU
- For smaller input sizes, depending on the platform, it might be faster using the CPU than the GPU (**if anyone can tell me why/how to improve my Thrust code to make it faster for smaller input sizes, that would be great!**)